# Get language in android?

Tags: android

In my android app I need to know which is the language of the phone in this format :fr (for francais), en (for english),etc.. How can I do this? I know that I can display language with this :

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()
```

but the result is francais,english,...

Can I obtain somehow the initials of languages?

Comment: because I need the to put at a link. For example, if the language is francais the link will be something like this "http://www.something/fr, if is english will be "http//www.somthing/en"...

Comment: Take a look at getISO3Language() http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getISO3Language()

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

Returns the language code for this Locale or the empty string if no language was set.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage%28%29)

Answer (score 6):

How about using

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

Comment: This should be correct, but it actually returns "English", "Español", etc, exactly as getDisplayLocale()..... why?!?!?!?!

Comment: I cant find any method called "getDisplayLocale() on the class Locale. Which API level or SDK are you using?

Comment: @matteo  It should return "en", "es", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try one of these two. 
`Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`
This will give language iso code i.e. "de", "ru". 
**OR**

```
Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
```

This returns global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources.